# Power BI filtering URL query Parameters

Tags: powerbi

I am trying to filter the Power BI reports using the URL query filters.The field name I am trying to filter has space so I am passing in the parameter like
`?filter=DW_Project/Project_x0020_Manager_x0020_Name eq 'Max Hex'`

But the reports are being filtered

[image]

I am getting the error like

[image]

Can anyone please tell what I am missing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The encoding looks correct. Indeed the space is escaped with `_x0020_` as per [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-url-filters#special-characters-in-url-filters). Check the name of the table and the field and make sure they are the same. Note that these names are case sensitive. You will get this error if they do not match. Since you posted only images, I can't check, but `DW__Project` looks like containing not one, but two underscores, while it is only one in your URL.